# Morphisms contracting a family of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, projective-morphisms

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of normal projective varieties. Let $S\subseteq X$ be a surface admitting a morphism $g:S\rightarrow C$ to a curve $C$ such that any fiber of $g$ is a curve.

Assume that the general fiber of $g$ is contracted to a point by $f$. Is it true that any fiber of $g$ is contracted by $f$?

Comment: Yes, that is true.  Consider the inverse image under $f$ of a general hyperplane section.  The intersection with $S$ is a curve ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this is true in more generality:

- You don't need $f, X$, or $Y$ to be normal or projective (this is of course, trivial, they are all red herrings). You only need $g$ to be proper (I suppose you meant that $S$ is a projective surface, so that's covered).
- If all the fibers of $g$ are connected and **any** fiber of $g$ is contracted, then all fibers are contracted. This is known as the "There are no bowties in algebraic geometry" theorem (or more conventionally called "Rigidity Lemma").
- From your formulation it seems that you are assuming that $C$ is irreducible. Because of the previous point you only need connected, but that is obviously necessary.

The proof is not too hard, and you should try. I believe this was first proved by Mumford when $S=F\times C$ and $g$ is the projection. A good place to look for the proof of this more general statement is Lemma 1.6 in [Kollár-Mori98](https://books.google.com/books?id=YrysxvPbBLwC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=rigidity%20lemma&f=false).

Comment: Indeed, it seems Jason's hint suffices.

Comment: Roy: I am not sure how that works if you only know that a special fiber is contracted. In that case the general hyperplane section will miss the point where that special fiber maps and thus does not give any information. No?

Comment: Thanks Sandor:  let's try this:  If a general hyperplane section H misses the point to which a special fiber contracts, then the pullback curve Z of H (in S) misses that fiber, hence its image by g does not surject onto C.  Thus its image meets C only in a finite number of points (if C is irreducible). Hence Z meets only a finite number of fibers of g and thus consists of a union of a finite number of them.  are we getting there?  i.e. then most fibers of g map to points via f, so we are in the situation of the generic fiber of g being collapsed.  Does this scan?

Comment: Hi Roy, this sounds good. It's a nice proof assuming that $Y$ is projective. The statement is still true assuming that $g$ is proper and $f$ is arbitrary (plus the connectivity assumptions). (Which is what I had in mind all along so I thought that there cannot be such a simple proof. But there is one with $Y$ projective). Cheers! :)